# Pushing small amounts of data to and from device

Tags: android

I'm looking at developing an app that would need to send/receive small amounts of data (50 - 200 characters) to and from the device. I was looking into XMPP for this, I was wondering if there are any other ways I should consider.

Thanks
Jon

Comment: You need to be more specific about the requirements for this project. Where do you need to send the data? How often? Will you be guaranteed internet access?

Comment: Adding to what @ethan asked, over what transport layer?  i.e. Bluetooth, WiFi, USB, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It would be useful to understand some more requirements and constraints, but if you will not send too often and if you are concerned about power and coverage don't rule out SMS (allowing for the typical 160 characters max that might require multiple messages).

With the right price plan (i.e. enough free or cheap SMS) it means you don't have to worry about 3G coverage or require setting up a GPRS/Edge/3G data connection (which means more processing so in theory more power - certainly 3G will mean more power than 2G as a rule)

You do need to bear in mind that SMS is not guaranteed messaging and you might require some higher level acknowledgement.

Comment: You might want to use an HTTP connection (maybe even secure?) to target a php screen. You could send/receive an xml stream to update a MySQL database. Look at HttpUrlConnection and HttpsUrlConnection. For small amounts of data (up to 8k) it's pretty fast.